# dlib installation failed on OS X Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, python-2.7, cmake, pip, dlib

I wanted to install dlib for Python 2.7 on OS X Yosemite 10.10. I tried both through pip and manual installation, and the error is the same in both cases. Below I am providing traceback from pip installation and the contents of CMakeError.log file.

```
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
    -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
    -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
    CMake Error at /private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/use_cpp_11.cmake:74 (target_compile_features):
      target_compile_features The compiler feature "cxx_thread_local" is not
      known to CXX compiler

      "Clang"

      version 7.0.2.7000181.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:770 (enable_cpp11_for_target)


    -- Building a C++11 test project to see if your compiler supports C++11
    -- ********** Your compiler failed to build a C++11 project.  C++11 is required to use all parts of dlib! **********
    -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
    -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
    -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X
    -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X - Success
    -- C++11 activated (compiler doesn't have full C++11 support).
    -- Found Python with installed numpy package
    -- Numpy include path '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
    -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
    -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
    -- LTO enabled
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/setup.py", line 249, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/setup.py", line 129, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/setup.py", line 163, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-vW_HWD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/45/0flgc1fd2y34rcnttzrxz5d80000gr/T/pip-build-4I4QuR/dlib/
```

And this is what is in the CMakeError.log file:

```
    Determining if the function sgetrf_single exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/Meruyert/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_2cace/fast"
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=sgetrf_single -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.10.3/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_2cace
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.10.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=sgetrf_single -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cace.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_2cace /usr/lib/libcblas.dylib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sgetrf_single", referenced from:
      _main in CheckFunctionExists.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [cmTC_2cace] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_2cace/fast] Error 2
```

Any help or advice how to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The message about actual error is **above**  the line `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev sorry, didn't noticed that. I've updated the question.

Comment: Your version of Clang is too new for the version of CMake you're using. Try with the latest _releases_ of CMake (3.11.0) and Clang (6.0). BTW, `dlib` `cmake`'s just fine with CMake 3.10.2 and macOS High Sierra's default Clang and Python.

Comment: @nega Thank you very much!